# what type is returned by json_array_elements(json)?

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm having trouble understanding how to use json_array_elements() in postgres.

I want to declare a variable to hold the results of json_array_elements(some_json_data_array), in order to perform operations on the rows. I can't figure out how to make this work.

so that it would look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$

DECLARE 
    mydata somedatatype := json_array_elements(New.data);
BEGIN
 do something with mydata
```

Is this possible? Or I am getting something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html)

> Expands a JSON array to a set of JSON elements.
>
> json_array_elements('[1,true, [2,false]]')

1
true
[2,false]

[Also, check this answer on specific DB related forum](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array)

Comment: what i would like to find out is what I need to put instead of 'somedatatype' in my declaration.

Comment: `json[]` .... On a related topic, [check this page](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/the-lazy-analysts-guide-to-postgres-json.html) on some ways to use it.